# Why this snake does not move?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have a web page with a snake that the user should control with buttons.

I used a `for` loop to bind the click event to the buttons. The move should happen in the `if` statement, but the snake does not move.

Why does it not work?

```js
const squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
const snake = document.querySelector(".snake");
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btns > button");
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
  
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; ++i) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    x += 100;
    if(e.target.innerHTML.trim() === "right") {
        snake.style.left = x;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.snake { display: inline-block; position: absolute; border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<div class="btns"><button class="button">right</button></div>
<div class="snake">SNAKE</div>
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Please create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and also read [What is a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: I turned your code into a runnable snippet, adding some minimal HTML/CSS. Please update it if needed.

Comment: To those commenting about using a debugger. Please note that when you debug and inspect `x` it has the expected value, while `style.left` remains empty. This just confirms that the move is not happening. The question then still is "why?". This question does **not** need more debugging details.

Comment: @trincot Well, but unless at least some html and css is shown, nobody knows, what for instance the `innerHTML` of the clicked button really is. Or if there even is at least one button selected by `document.querySelectorAll(".btns > button");`  Or if the `snake` does have any particular styling that prevents `left` from getting effective ... So if one then discovers on debugging, that the eventhandler is indeed executed and the assignment is indeed happening, you can still ask "why doesn't the element move?". But until that is clear, it can have any reason ...

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the unit of measure when defining `style.left`. Just a number is not enough. So add "px":

```js
const squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
const snake = document.querySelector(".snake");
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btns > button");
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
  
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; ++i) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    x += 100;
    if(e.target.innerHTML.trim() === "right") {
        snake.style.left = x + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.snake { display: inline-block; position: absolute; border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<div class="btns"><button class="button">right</button></div>
<div class="snake">SNAKE</div>
```